# How to disable Bluetooth by default?

Tags: bluetooth

I want `Bluetooth` disabled by default. How to do it in elementary os? I've already tried to disable it in settings. But there is no option for this. If I disable it on top bar and login and logout the Bluetooth is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it by adding next line to `/etc/rc.local` file with following system restart:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: This solution "blocks" the bluetooth "widget" too. Isn't there any solution that only "switch off" the bluetooth like the widget does?

Comment: Elementary OS 6 does not present this file.

Answer (score 4):

Open `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and change `AutoEnable=true` to `AutoEnable=false`.

Comment: Didn't work on `elementary OS 5.0 juno`

Comment: Worked for me in `Elementary OS 6 (built on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)`